# Run VBscript code that is sent through form POST

Tags: post, asp-classic, vbscript

I'd like to have a classic ASP page that works similar to a jsfiddle except for VBscript this time. In other words, I need to display the output of vbscript code that is passed from one form to a page using POST.

Obviously, `response.write(request.form())` doesn't work and I don't even know how if it's possible. I can see how a script could write the form input into a separate .asp page (using `filesystemobject` and `writeline`) which is then loaded, but is there a more elegant way as to not have a temporary page for each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the execute() function (not to be confused with server.execute()).

Here is an example:

```
<%
    if request.QueryString("task") = "execute" then
        Response.Write "Output: <hr />"
        Execute(Request.Form("VbScript"))
        Response.Write "<hr />"
    end if
%>
<form action="test.asp?task=execute" method="post">
<textarea name="VbScript" style="height: 100px">
x = 4 - 3
response.write x
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Execute" />
</form>
```

However, whilst this is fun, i cant think of a single use where security wouldnt be a major concern.

Your essentially giving the user full access to your server!

Comment: thanks a lot! this is for an internal developer tool so no risk there.